# ¿Cómo concatenar la fecha en un archivo de texto?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un código en JavaScript que me lista el contenido de un directorio cada 5 segundos y me crea un archivo de texto con los contenidos del mismo, pero ahora cuando los quiero diferenciar por fecha y hora me tira error la ejecución.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
function fileFunc() {
  exec(`ls >> content${new Date().toISOString()}.txt`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
  });
}

setInterval(() => {
    fileFunc();
}, 5000);
clearInterval(fileFunc);
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el error que lanza?

Comment: Ahí añadí screenshot del error.

Comment: No puedes utilizar `:` en nombres de archivos. Quita los dos puntos de la cadena, en la hora para que el nombre quede algo así así: `content22-06-12T144035` o así `content22-06-12T14-40-35` si reemplazas los dos puntos por un guión medio

Comment: Otra opción es usar el valor de milisegundos desde Unix Epoch, luego ordenar cronológicamente es directo. [`(new Date()).valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)